# AWS Lambda function to start multiple instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I just created this function in AWS Lambda to start multiple instances. However when i run the test, it only starts one of the instances instead all the instances in the array. Is this a problem with how i have my array defined in the function? Lambda did not throw a json error so i assumed all was well. I am using the Node.js 4.3 runtime format.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({region: 'us-west-1'});
ec2.startInstances({InstanceIds : (['i-a11111'],['i-a22222'],['i-a33333'],['i-a44444']) },function (err, data) {
if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
else console.log(data); // successful response
context.done(err,data);
});
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the AWS JavaScript SDK documentation, the `InstanceIds` parameter is supposed to be an array of strings:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#startInstances-property

This should be the correct format:

```
{ InstanceIds : ['i-a11111','i-a22222','i-a33333','i-a44444'] }
```

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly now

Comment: Happy to have helped.  Feel free to mark it as the accepted answer, to complete the typical Stack Overflow workflow. ;-)